Camel 3 -> 4 unitOfWork
I am trying to update from camel 3 to 4, but i have an issue with the following line,
camelContext.adapt(ExtendedCamelContext.class).setUnitOfWorkFactory(new CustomUnitOfWorkFactory());

I found already this post:
Apache Camel adapt() method removed in version 4
So with the help of that I transformed it into:
    ExtendedCamelContext context = camelContext
            .getCamelContextExtension()
            .getContextPlugin(ExtendedCamelContext.class);

but on the extended camel context the setUnitOfWorkFactory doesnt seem to be available anymore.
Does someone know how to set this in camel 4.6

In the end the solution was quite simple.
if you dont use spring boot
camelContext.getRegistry().bind("customUnitOfWorkFactory", new CustomUnitOfWorkFactory());

if you use spring boot make it a component
@Component
public class CustomUnitOfWorkFactory implements UnitOfWorkFactory {

